# Why does a call to read() block forever

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

I'm facing a puzzling problem that started rather recently.

I have a program that uses one thread to write into a file, and another thread to read from that file.
Both thread uses a different file descriptor. The writer thread has opened the file using a O_WRONLY flag, the reader thread has opened the file in O_RDONLY mode.
As far as the logic is concerned, the reader thread has no idea about what the writer thread is doing, and both could be using a different file for that matter.

The writer thread write continuously to the file at regular interval (data comes from a device stream at up to 20Mbit/s).

The reader thread reads the file at regular interval too.

Here is the reader loop:

```
while (tot < sz)
{
    LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC +
        QString("read(%1) -- begin").arg(sz-tot));
    ret = read(fd2, (char *)data + tot, sz - tot);
    LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC +
        QString("read(%1) -> %2 end").arg(sz).arg(ret));

    if ((sz - tot) != ret)
    {
        LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC + QString("errno = %1").arg(errno));
    }

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
        {
            LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC +
                QString("read(%1) -> %2 EAGAIN").arg(sz).arg(ret));
            usleep(1000);
            continue;
        }

        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR,
            LOC + "File I/O problem in 'safe_read()'" + ENO);

        errcnt++;
        numfailures++;
        if (errcnt == 3)
            break;
    }
    else if (ret > 0)
    {
        tot += ret;
    }
    [...snipped...]
}
```

You can see that I show a log before read is called, and right after it returned.
From time to time, read will be called, and it will never come back...

```
2014-02-19 11:24:10.156417 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): write(65424) cnt 1 total 5076
2014-02-19 11:24:10.156466 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): total written so far: 26934760 bytes
2014-02-19 11:24:10.156514 D  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): read(65536) -- begin
2014-02-19 11:24:10.190769 D  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): read(65536) -> 60968 end
2014-02-19 11:24:10.190781 I  RingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): safe_read(...@1698944, 65536) -> 65536, took 60 ms (8.73813Mbps)
2014-02-19 11:24:10.190786 D  RingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): total read so far: 26930304 bytes
2014-02-19 11:24:10.190795 I  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): read(65536) -- begin
2014-02-19 11:24:10.195917 D  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): read(65536) -> 4456 end
2014-02-19 11:24:10.195927 D  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): errno = 0
2014-02-19 11:24:10.206445 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): write(65424) cnt 1 total 1692
2014-02-19 11:24:10.206489 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): total written so far: 27000184 bytes
2014-02-19 11:24:10.256103 D  FileRingBuf(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg): read(61080) -- begin
2014-02-19 11:24:10.256499 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): write(47376) cnt 1 total 40984
2014-02-19 11:24:10.262073 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): total written so far: 27047560 bytes
2014-02-19 11:24:10.273385 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): write(65424) cnt 1 total 940
2014-02-19 11:24:10.385495 D  TFW(/external/recordings/1001_20140219002351.mpg:64): total written so far: 27112984 bytes
```

You can see here that the writer has written 26934760 bytes to the disk. The read so far has read 26930304 bytes, so we are 4456 bytes from EOF. A 64kB read is then attempted, reads returns almost immediately with 4456 bytes. So far so good.
Immediately, another read is attempted for 61080 bytes (65536-4456).

Very shortly after, the writer thread writes to file once again.
The 64kB read is now waiting forever, and won't come out for another 30+ seconds.

So any particular ideas on why a read would suddenly block forever?

Edit: From looking at the behaviour, the blockage always seems to happen once read has reached EOF and returned early, if you immediately retry a read before a new write occurred. In which case, read will not exit for several seconds (usually 20+)

Comment: Dunno if this helps, but from the [man-page for `open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html): *There are many infelicities in the protocol underlying NFS, affecting amongst others `O_SYNC` and `O_NDELAY`*

Comment: I would have to comment that applications using NFS is poor design, and applications that simultaneously write and read the same file ditto. Use a database, or a socket if you don't need to keep the data.

Comment: @paddy O_NDELAY (or O_NONBLOCK) should have no effect with regular files.

Comment: @EJP Application doesn't have to use NFS. The files written and read are usually GB in sizes and it's done that way to stream live television. While yes, if you were to always read at the end of the file there would be better way to do this: realise that you may not watch the live television in real time. Like you're watching 5 minutes behind the EOF. So what would your great design do? cache GB of files so you don't re-read it? This is part of the mythtv project. There's no way you would place GB of files in a database. Now that would be poor design.

Comment: That quote did say *"amongst others"*...  I just thought I'd point out that there are obviously documented issues with NFS.  I agree with @EJP's comment about using sockets to transfer data.  In my work with television, I used TCP for streaming live video between machines.  There's no way I would rely on a file system for doing that.

Comment: @paddy you misunderstood. TCP *is* used to transmit the data between machines. This issue is on the streaming server, the same streaming server records the data, and stream it to client. And as I mentioned, the issue isn't just with NFS... I'm going to remove that point as it's causing too much confusion

Comment: So why is the streaming server reading it from file when it's also writing it to file?  Shouldn't it just accept the data from wherever it comes from, write it to file and stream it out to clients?  If you have two separate processes for this, they can communicate via a local socket which should have no impact on other sockets.  Or indeed a pipe.

Comment: sigh.... As I mentioned earlier what the server is streaming may not be what is recording at the present moment. So you start watching live TV; the client pause playback. 5 minutes later it resumes. The server would have continued to record and is now streaming at a position in the file that is GB before the EOF. Only way to cater for this is totally separate the writer and the reader, you're not going to cache GB of data in RAM to prevent accessing the disk again. Can we focus on the problem at hand?

Comment: You put it much more clearly that time.  I did not get that from the original question.  Try not to get frustrated when people are putting their own time into helping you solve a problem.  Your head is all around it, because you wrote it, whereas the rest of us have no idea where you're coming from until you say...  So, as you described the issue, this locks up when the reader tries to read bytes from the same part of the file that's being written.  Have you tried always "reading behind" the writer (so that the bytes being read can never overlap the bytes being written)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...

I've discovered the issue and how to work around it.

As mentioned in the original question, the blockage always seems to happen once read has reached EOF, returned early and immediately retry a read (before a new write occurred to the file).

Under this scenario, read() will not exit for several seconds (usually over 20 seconds)

So the work around is to record how many bytes we've read so far so it knows where it's up to in the file, and call fstat to check the size of the file. From that, make sure we never call read() if we're already at the end of the file or ask read() to retrieve more bytes than there are in the file.

```
struct stat sb;
off_t current_pos = internalreadpos;

while (tot < sz)
{
    off_t toread = sz - tot;
    bool read_ok = true;

    // check that we have some data to read,
    // so we never attempt to read past the end of file
    // if fstat errored or isn't a regular file, default to previous behavior
    ret = fstat(fd2, &sb);
    if (ret == 0 && S_ISREG(sb.st_mode))
    {
        if (current_pos >= sb.st_size)
        {
            // We're at the end, don't attempt to read
            read_ok = false;
            LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC + "not reading, reached EOF");
        }
        else
        {
            toread = min(sb.st_size - current_pos, toread);
            if (toread < (sz-tot))
            {
                LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG,
                    LOC + QString("About to reach EOF, reading %1 wanted %2")
                    .arg(toread).arg(sz-tot));
            }
        }
    }

    if (read_ok)
    {
        LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC +
            QString("read(%1) -- begin").arg(toread));
        ret = read(fd2, (char *)data + tot, toread);
        LOG(VB_FILE, LOG_DEBUG, LOC +
            QString("read(%1) -> %2 end").arg(toread).arg(ret));
    }
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
            continue;

        LOG(VB_GENERAL, LOG_ERR,
            LOC + "File I/O problem in 'safe_read()'" + ENO);

        errcnt++;
        numfailures++;
        if (errcnt == 3)
            break;
    }
    else if (ret > 0)
    {
        tot += ret;
        current_pos += ret;
    }

    if (oldfile)
        break;

    if (ret == 0) // EOF returns 0
    {
        if (tot > 0)
            break;

        zerocnt++;

        // 0.36 second timeout for livetvchain with usleep(60000),
        // or 2.4 seconds if it's a new file less than 30 minutes old.
        if (zerocnt >= (livetvchain ? 6 : 40))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```